# can you see the name of the person who purchased with the credit card online?

Tags: credit-card, online-payment, paypal

if you order something online via PayPal, can the person see the name of the person who purchased it on their credit card?

Comment: It might depend on the platform. Are they selling via a 3rd party system, or is the PayPal option on their own website?

Comment: Is this a question more about money or privacy?

Answer (score 1):

On the systems I've seen, yes, the customer name (and sometimes billing address) is visible.

The paranoid's solution would be to purchase prepaid cards, which do not have a cardholder identity associated with them. I don't know what info they do provide.

Answer (score 0):

Usually yes, as that is the information given to them, technically they aren't legally able to use that information in any way, or sell it/give it to anybody else.

It's just a verification measure. If someone were to steal your credit card and use it, with their name rather than yours. When you go and make a claim against a fraudulent transaction, that information would show up and then make claiming your money back much easier.

Comment: If someone were to steal the card and use it, what prevents them from entering the name that is printed on the card when they are asked for the cardholder's name?